# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know the alternating series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$$ converges by doing the alternating series test, but I can't seem to find a way to prove $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$$ converges. I tried it with  $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sqrt[n] \frac{1}{n^3} $ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, but both of these result in 1, which means you can't conclude anything from them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The corresponding integral converges.

Comment: Hint: For $n\geq 2$, $$
\frac{1}{{n^3 }} < \frac{1}{{n^2 }} < \frac{1}{{(n - 1)n}} = \frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}.
$$

Comment: Now you've learned several solutions, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) may interest you.

Comment: In what textbook of calculus is this an exercise? The geometric series and p-series are standard examples when talking about infinite series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{n^3}}$ converges by the [P-Series Test](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/p-series.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^3}\,\mathrm dx$ converges, your series converges too, by the integral test.

Answer (score 1):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach the relies on straightforward elementary analysis only.  To that end, we now proceed.**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{(n-1)^2}-\frac1{n^2}&=\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac1{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2}-1\right)\\\\
&\ge \frac2{n^3}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Summing the telescoping sum and applying the inequality in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
1-\frac1{N^2}&=\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\frac1{(n-1)^2}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\\\\
&\ge 2\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1{n^3}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^3}\le \frac32-\frac1{2N^2}$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem we see that the series of interest converges to a value of less than $3/2$.

> **TOOLS USED:  Telescoping series, the squeeze theorem, elementary inequalities**

Comment: I don't really know how I could improve your answer, it seems fine to me, it's nice to see someone using a different approach than normal.

Comment: Pleased to hear!